# How to allow users to create groups with Organic Groups

Tags: organic-groups

How do I allow users on my site to create groups. I've done the initial configuration of Organic Groups, there is no 'Create Group' button by default. I want users to be able to create groups under a Parent Group.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Parent Group"?

Answer (score 0):

Groups are just a special kind of nodes, so you just need to go to Permissions and grant users the right to create nodes of that bundle. Users can create groups by going to `yourwebsite.com/node/add/nameofyourgroupnode`. There is also a menu link by default.